# Send mesh to a video card with the help of ngui instead of DragonBones in Unity

Tags: unity, video, ngui, visualization

I am working at the project. It is pretty huge. And there is ngui at its core, so I can not go away from it (from ngui).

Now I am assigned to incorporate the DragonBones into the project. There are visual elements made with DragonBones which are (those elements) displayed behind the ngui elements.

I know that ngui works as follows: it gathers all the meshes and sends them all to the video card at once.

Is it possible to make DragonBones put the meshes in that gathering, so that DragonBones visual elements were sent to the video card along with ngui elements and hence were displayed in accordance with ngui elements?

Will extending the `UIBasicSprite` help me to tackle the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, without (very detailed) information of how DragonBones works, this question is not answerable. I have never heard of that asset before, although it [appears to have a git repository](https://github.com/DragonBones/DragonBonesCSharp/tree/master/Unity). A cursory glance shows that it uses its own Canvas. You should be able to change the canvas used (or change the rendering order) pretty easily.

Comment: @Draco18s, how did you figure out that it uses the canvas?

Comment: [`[ExecuteInEditMode,RequireComponent(typeof(CanvasRenderer), typeof(RectTransform))]`](https://github.com/DragonBones/DragonBonesCSharp/blob/master/Unity/src/DragonBones/Scripts/unity/UnityUGUIDisplay.cs#L29).

Comment: @Draco18s, I think I should use [the](https://github.com/thomaschampagne/NGUI270Revive/blob/master/Assets/NGUI270Revive/Scripts/Internal/UIWidget.cs) class somehow. And namely I think that the onFill method should be overridden. Am I thinking right or no?

Comment: No idea, honestly.